# How to pass a Screen props when using a stack navigator expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Im trying to pass a params into my tab for all the 3 windows I have. I just don't know were to place `ScreenProps` here and if that is the correct approach for sending a params into the the 3 classes. does the params also need to be passed in this class or when I navigate to the tab after login `this.props.navigation.navigate('Main',{name: "1"})` simply trying to pass the name 1 right now to get it in all the tabs

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import Profile from '../screens/ProfileToUse';


const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
 Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
     focused={focused}
     name={
       Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
        : 'md-information-circle'
    }
  /> 
 )
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
 });

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Contacts',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
     <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
       name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-link${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-link'}
     />
   ),
 };

  const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: Profile,
  });

 ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
     <TabBarIcon
     focused={focused}
     name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-profile'}
     />
   ),
 };


export default createBottomTabNavigator({
HomeStack,
LinksStack,
ProfileStack,
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: true,
    activeTintColor: '#F8F8F8',
    inactiveTintColor: '#586589',
    style: {
     backgroundColor: '#273746'
   },
    tabStyle: {}
  }
},


);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass screenprops to one screen at a time, calling `this.props.navigation.navigate('Main',{name: "1"})` in the first screen , and ond componentDidMount() you call `var p = this.props.navigation.getParam('name'||'No name')` .

You might wanna use some libraries to avoid this, like Redux, or https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-props-mapper , even reactn.

Comment: When I pass it to main it goes to the class above how can I actually see it in a my class `props.navigation` does not get the value

Comment: You didn't posted a class... you navigate to a screen , then to access it  paste this in the page that you navigated to `componendDidMount(){var p = this.props.navigation.getParam('name'||'No name'); alert(p) }` , you chould ckeck the basic documentation before posting here  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html